# Install Air Application in Android without Adobe Air

Tags: java, android, apache-flex, mobile, air

I developed a Adobe Air Application and I discovered that the Mobile I am trying to install the application is not compatible with the Adobe Air's supported devices because this wasn't launched yet.
So, how can I solve this?

I have some ideas:

1. Is possible to change the Mobile Name to fake another device and Adobe Air not refuse the installation?
2. Is possible to convert AIR to Java?
3. Is possible to run Air without Java?
4. Abandon Flash and do it in Java or Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Captive Runtime on Android since AIR 3.0, just like on iOS. That way you won't need to have AIR installed as the runtime will be bundled within the app.

If you're using Flash Builder, check out this link : [Captive Runtime packaging in Air 3.0](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2011/10/11/captive-runtime-packaging-in-air-3-0/).

If not, follow this one instead : [Installation and deployment options in Adobe AIR 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html)

Comment: Great solution, but this not solved my problem, this way did run In compatible devices, but in the devices that is not compatible with Adobe Air this wasnt run.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could try to get a hint as to if the maker of the device intends on making it AIR compatible?

Comment: Thank you Exort, I think that i solved the problem running Flash at Mobile Browser.

Comment: As Adobe has curtailed development of Flash in the mobile Android browser, that may not be the most ideal solution. What is the phone you're trying to get this to work on? There might be a very good reason why AIR doesn't run on that device.

Answer (score 1):

1-i didn't get the first part, but if you mean to run app on ios and bb, you have to compile it to both cause of kernel mapping

---

2- you can't convert AIR to JDK but u can invoke java methods in adobe air using BlazeDS, instead if u are a professional java programmer you may use java FX(not sure if u can run it on mobiles)

---

3-adobe AIR is an independent platform, you don't need to have java to run Air, also u can embed AIR vm in your AIR app, so user doesn't has to install AIR vm on mobile check out

### http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-flash-professional-cs6-/creating-a-prepackaged-air-app/

4- javascript can not do wht actionscript do, anyway there is HTM5 which can bring your app alive on HTML, there is TypeScript from microsoft as a replacement of javascript.